# Node html-pdf not showing encoded image urls in PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, charts, html-pdf

I am using `html-pdf` node package to generate the PDF but recently, I am having an issue with my encoded image URLs are not working in `img` tag.

It works on my MAC though but not on sever which is Ubuntu.

Please advise.

code sample:

```
<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?c=%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%0A%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%27January%27%2C%20%27February%27%2C%20%27March%27%2C%20%27April%27%2C%20%27May%27%2C%20%27June%27%2C%20%27July%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Dataset%201%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B-31%2C%2070%2C%20-30%2C%2033%2C%20-9%2C%2014%2C%20-41%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20options%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20legend%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20scales%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xAxes%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gridLines%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yAxes%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gridLines%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%0A"
                    alt="Not found" style="width:100%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after upgrading the latest `html-pdf@3.0.0` `npm` package it didn't work. So I had to download the image first and then pass the image URL to the HTML template. That worked for me.